# Avoid specific numbers in questions

Tags: discussion, questions

This is my first Meta question, so if it is not correctly asked or out of place please let me know so I can learn.

I think that questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956610/how-to-select-first-10-words-of-a-sentence), [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript) and in general, all questions that involve a fixed amount of something (that could perfectly be variable) should have more generic titles.

This could produce more generic answers that could apply in more cases and eventually will help people looking for something similar. Not everyone knows exactly how to search correctly in Google and other search engines.

Comment: In an ideal world, everything would be perfect. I don't see what you're proposing to happen here. Sure titles *should* be better written than they usually are, what do you suggest we do about it?

Comment: Maybe edit the questions? I posted this because I wanted to edit those questions but was not sure if it was the right things to do.

Comment: Those questions specifically? No, the answers would then also have to be edited. Those questions have reasonably high views and votes, so are already good google juice. I see no reason to edit those questions.

Comment: Related: [Should we rename tag 'greatest-n-per-group' to 'top-n-per-group', to be consistent with 'top-n'?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337459/should-we-rename-tag-greatest-n-per-group-to-top-n-per-group-to-be-consiste)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it matters. If I search for those posts using different numbers, those posts still rank highly in search results.

- [Round to 4 decimal places in JavaScript](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Round+to+4+decimal+places+in+JavaScript) - Third result.
- [php select first 5 words of a sentence](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20select%20first%205%20words%20of%20a%20sentence) - First result.

I guess Google is already taking care of this for us on their end.

Comment: The problem comes when people insist rounding to 5 decimal places is different to rounding to 4... and ask a new question to that effect.

Comment: @Braiam Five close votes solve that problem. (Not saying it's not a real problem. The search results above prove you right.)

Comment: Google saves the day again!

Answer (score 4):

You should consider using tags and flag questions as duplicates, if you think that answer to 'N items' question can be found elsewhere.

My favourite tag is greatest-n-per-group, it should be present in a third of SQL related questions.

Comment: [Should we rename tag 'greatest-n-per-group' to 'top-n-per-group', to be consistent with 'top-n'?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337459/should-we-rename-tag-greatest-n-per-group-to-top-n-per-group-to-be-consiste)

Comment: `top-n` is used substantially less times compared to `greatest-n-per-group` so that will not justify the change.

Comment: So what? `top-n` is the open-source/R/Python term, `greatest` is the SQL term. R/Python use is increasing, SQL is decreasing, certainly within data science. (Do we just wait until say 2025 then rename it?) Meantime, what's your constructive suggestion? Crossreference each tag from the other? Or else what?

Comment: No, they shouldn't be closed-as-duplicate, if they're written in a totally different language, using different terminology, and different tags. My intent here is to hep the two communities find each other's thematically-related Q&A, and at a basic level be aware of each other's approaches.

Comment: How come SQL use is decreasing in data science? It might be called Hive or BigQuery but it only means that SQL is here to stay for a very long time. R has `head` function, but I never heard about `top` in R.