# Should we rename tag 'greatest-n-per-group' to 'top-n-per-group', to be consistent with 'top-n'?

Tags: discussion, tags, terminology

We have [top-n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/top-n) but [greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group).
[top-n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/top-n) is the more standard term, for Python/pandas/R.
[greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) is used for SQL questions, since `GREATEST` is an actual keyword; Python and R people never use it. The entire Python/R and SWL communities are talking past each other. They will never even find each other's Q&A.** To prove this, just click through on each tag, you'll see the total lack of communication; this alone is unacceptable.

**Proposal:** shouldn't we rename the latter [top-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/top-n-per-group)? Here are multiple considerations:

- **consistency**
- to help it get found more easily (I've been an SO user for 7 years but only found [greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) today)
- **brevity**. There is no need to insert the 39-character word-salad "How to find top-n per group in X with Y..." and clutter every single title. You can just click on the tag. Again, it's much easier to search on one tag than a phrase of 8+ words.
- hard to see how to be language-agnostic, though
- if we shouldn't rename, should we at least crossmention each tag from the other's wiki?

**Not part of the proposal:** one user seems to think this is some backdoor plan to close, or implicitly cause to be closed, questions in one language community by people from the other community. That's off-topic and not being discussed or implied here.

Comment: I find it difficult to find this tag sometimes. I would rather just use a more generic `n-per-group`, as usually in questions it refers to `first`, `last`, `greatest`, `least`, or even `random`. The core of the problem is getting `n` rows from a group.

Comment: BRB, posting some burnination requests :P

Comment: @Bulat: `top-n` is the established term, at least in the Python/R/open-source community; SQL people say `greatest`. I think it's fairly implicit that we can generically flip any solution to least by sorting on minus the value, or using keyword `least`. Given that both tags are already massively underused, changing them to the obscure `n-per-group` wouldn't work, sadly. By the way, yes the core of the problem is getting n rows from a group, but that doesn't always mean we're operating on tables, or tables with a grouping; sometimes you see hashes/ sets/ other data structure approaches.

Comment: I'm still figuring out why would this be any different of using "How to find great/top n per group in X with Y, blabla" title.

Comment: Braiam: a) because it's **more efficiency and brevity** to describe that in one tag, rather then repeating that 39-character word salad and cluttering the title everytime. b) using a common tag would fix the problem I diagnosed here whereby the R/Python community and SQL community's Q&A are talking past each other. **Since both all the terms and tags they use are essentially disjoint, they will never even find each other's questions.** Which prevents them learning from each other.

Comment: @Braiam: the question had already explained why; I just rewrote it yet another time to make it even more clear why. I don't appreciate the downvote. If you have a constructive suggestion for/against, please tell us it? It's self-evident that searching on one tag beats a phrase of 8+ words.

Comment: Errr... Tags are not meant to be used that way. A tag *reason de etre* is to connect questions with the people that are able to answer them.

Comment: @Braiam, this is the way tags are meant to be used - for the same underlying concept. **Algorithmically, there is commonality between the R/Python and SQL.** The code is obviously different. Considerations like scalability, vectorization, big-O notation will remain the same. This does connect questions with the people that are able to answer them.

Comment: *[A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a **means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer** by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)* That's how SE says tags are meant to be used. This is supported by the tag privileges, like the dupehammer and documentation. Basically, knowing about X tag, means that you have ubiquitous knowledge about what the tag represents and the question is within the domain. R guys closing SQL questions don't have this knowledge.

Comment: @Braiam: I knew all that already, and please stop misquoting me. I talked about *tagging* and *finding related questions*, using tags; also *titling* them efficiently and compactly. Noone ever mentioned *"closing"* them. Why are you bringing up closing? Your chain of assumptions is really bizarre.

Comment: *"Basically knowing about X tag, means that you have ubiquitous knowledge about what the tag represents and the question is within the domain"*. That's wrong, notwithstanding you seem to be motivated by some fear of a sudden flood of incorrect closings. There are tons of generic algorithmic tags e.g. [tag:poker], [tag:financial], [tag:prime-factoring] where even experts could find it hard to determine what's on-topic. But again, this question isn't about closing stuff. I can't understand your assumption that even if something was not correctly tagged, that somehow puts it on a path to closing.